# How to observe property change returned by object's method

Tags: javascript, web, reactive-programming, observable, watch

I'm working on login system and need to watch if user is logged in / out. The value which determines user login status is returned in following way:

```
Parse.User.current().id // returns id when logged in
Parse.User.current() // returns null when logged out
```

expected functionality (pseudocode):

```
watch( Parse.User.current().id, function (old_val, new_val) {
  console.log( 'User id has changed from: ', old_val, ' to: ', new_val );
});
// expected result: User id has changed from null to H4tn34vw0
```

I would like to keep wide browser support, like ie9+. I considered `Object.observe()` but it can watch object properties, not values returned by methods if i'm correct. Also using `setInterval()` and checking the object every second may not be a good idea for performance.

Answer (score 1):

That will probably not work as you expect. 
Because I'm pretty sure that `Parse.User.current()` returns a different Object each time it's called and at least a different object per user.
And you can't watch a property-change if the property doesn't change, but instead, the returned object does.

Create a login and a logout function and let these dispatch an event when a user logs in or out. Then you have something you can monitor/observe.